# Creating bonded interface with new Ubuntu Server 18.04 install does not work

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-bonding

**Final Update** I started fresh again with DHCP on the client LAN. It successfully installed and was able to resolve the address to grab updates. Since a bond was not created initially, I installed `ifenslave`, and configured the bond manually using the server LAN at the gateway. I applied the configuration with `netplan apply`, and everything started working. `ip route` shows the routing table with the correct gateway, and I can update, install, ping, etc. I do not know why this is failing on a fresh installation, and I'm not sure if this would work for an "answer," since I don't understand why it's failing in the first place. Perhaps this is a lack of knowledge issue and not an Ubuntu issue?

**Update 2** I cannot set up a bond at all, whether it be static or dhcp. I have to use DHCP on a single interface just to get the OS installed.

**Update** Setting up a static IP with a bonded interface does not work, but installing with DHCP does work. I've successfully installed the OS with a static IP and a bonded interface on many other servers, but this one is not working. I will see if I can manually set it up after everything installs and return with another update.

Brand new server out of the box. Brand new `Ubuntu 18.04` installation. Once I get to the network config screen, I create an active-backup bond.

```
Subnet: 192.168.64.0/18
Address: 192.168.64.92
Mode: active-backup
Nameservers: 192.168.70.80,192.168.3.222
```

Once the installation was complete, I realized I had no network. Couldn't ping internally or externally. I tried again, and looked at the full log. I saw this:

`Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease`

`Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'`

I have done this on **many** servers, and now this has happened on **two** new servers in a row. Every search I do, I only get results for `apt update`. This is a fresh install. Any ideas? I can't install packages, update, ping, nothing. And I can't find any resources because every example is for updating. First server I passed it off as a fluke, but now it's the 2nd server in a row.

There is no IP conflict, and I know with 100% certainty that my setup config is correct.

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed the network device is operational? 

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. The interfaces show up in the BIOS. This is a brand new Dell R440 with NON-RAID drive.

Comment: I started over with the installation and went with DHCP. It is downloading archives as I type this. I don't understand why it doesn't work upon initial setup, but I will try to manually create the bonded interface, static IP, etc and return with updates.